# Driver for Intel HD 3000 (Core i7 2630QM)

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

Ubuntu 11.10 can't recognize my intel HD 3000, where can i download the driver?

The ouput of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA is`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `lspci -vnn | grep VGA`. This is a mobile CPU, but the GPU should be the same as in my i5-2500k which works without a problem. Is this by any chance an Optimus notebook with an additional nVidia GPU?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: Could you detail what "can't recognize" means for you ? Any error message or something else not working ? It could help us giving you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intel provides an open source driver which is installed by default on Ubuntu.
Run `dpkg -s xserver-xorg-video-intel` to check the status of the driver package: it should be installed.

Ubuntu 11.10 should run just fine on [your hardware](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_corei7_2630qm&num=1). Having two computers with Intel's HD3000 and HD2000 GPUs i can confirm it. Since the Ubuntu 11.04 → 11.10 update, I no more need to use the [xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) and it's way more stable.

You could also try to upgrade to the [Linux 3.1 kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

If you still want to download the driver, you can look for [the xf86-video-intel source](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel/) or the [default package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel).

Comment: Agree with Maxime, using an i5-2410M on Ubuntu 11.10 with HD 3000 works right out of the box. No driver needed. Install mesa-utils and run "glxgears" to see that 3D rendering works.